Can't open keystore and truststore when passwords encrypted with securityUtility
I have configured my ssl configuration with my own key store and trust store and when I use passwords in clear text it all works as expected.
I then  encrypted passwords for my key store and trust store with:
./target/liberty/wlp/bin/securityUtility encode --encoding=hash 
I have entered encrypted passwords with {hash}xxxxx like below :
  <keyStore id="myKeyStore" location="resources/key.p12" type="PKCS12" password="{hash}blahbla"/>
  <keyStore id="myTrustStore" location="resources/trust.p12" type="PKCS12" password="{hash}blahblah"/>

I now get the following exceptions for both key store and trust store:
9/26/24 9:23:02:317 AEST] 00000020 com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil                        E CWWKS1857E: The password was not processed because an invalid password cipher exception was reported.
com.ibm.ws.crypto.util.InvalidPasswordCipherException: The decryption operation is not supported by the hash algorithm. 
    at com.ibm.ws.crypto.util.PasswordCipherUtil.decipher(PasswordCipherUtil.java:206)
    at com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.decode_password(PasswordUtil.java:638)
    at com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.decode(PasswordUtil.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore.decodePassword(WSKeyStore.java:1373)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore$1.run(WSKeyStore.java:849)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore$1.run(WSKeyStore.java:839)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore.obtainKeyStore(WSKeyStore.java:839)


I have added passwordUtilities-1.1 feature in server.xml but that didn't make any difference
Any ideas how I can fix it

The {hash} encoding is only supported for user passwords, not keystore passwords.
Doc for reference:
https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/command/securityUtility-encode.html
I would recommend using {aes} encoding (if you do not want to use the default, {xor}).

When you hash the password it is one-way and Liberty cannot retrieve it. Hash is typically used when there is a need to compare the passwords (like in basicRegistry user password for example).
Liberty needs the key store password to open up the key stores. You can. however, encrypt the password instead.
